# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException when printing an integer

Tags: groovy

```
static int exec(List<String> l) {
    l.add(0, isWin() ? "cmd.exe" : "sh")
    l.add(1, isWin() ? "/c" : "-c")                  // Adds a platform specific prefix
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(l)
    fine("Executing command: '" + l.join(" ") + "'") // Logging
    pb.inheritIO()
    Process p = pb.start()
    int i = p.waitFor()                              // Returns an integer
    println(i)                                       // The problematic line
    return i
}
```

causes

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: soc.util.Build$__clinit__closure1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: ([B, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer) values: [[48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...], ...]
```

But if I remove the println statement it works.
Replacing it with `System.out.println(i)` or `println(i as int)` or `println((int) i)`.
Setting `i` to a constant value also doesn't work.

Is this a known bug and can you circumvent this?

Comment: can You give wider fragment of code?

Comment: Please see if this helps - http://www.joergm.com/2010/09/executing-shell-commands-in-groovy/